# multiprocessing: assert self._popen is None, 'cannot start a process twice'

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I need multiple instances of a application to run under a controller.
Here is a simple multiprocessing skeleton I use:

```
bash-4.4$ cat controller.py
import os, sys
from worker import worker

if __name__ == '__main__':
        instances = 4

        for n in range(instances):
                        wkr_instance = worker(n)
                        wkr_instance.connect()
                        wkr_instance.start()
bash-4.4$ cat worker.py
import os
from multiprocessing import Process


class worker(Process):

        def __init__(self, n):
                self.name = "worker#" + str(n)
                print(self.name)
                super().__init__
        def connect(self):
                print("connected")

        def run(self):
                print("Running")
                while true:
                        pass
```

When I ran it, I got the following errors at the first run() call:

```
bash-4.4$ python3 controller.py
worker#0
connected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "controller.py", line 10, in <module>
    wkr_instance.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in start
    assert self._popen is None, 'cannot start a process twice'
AttributeError: 'worker' object has no attribute '_popen'
bash-4.4$
```

It looks like the start() method hasn't been run for the first time yet. Why it's complaining 'cannot start a process twice'?

Comment: In `worker.__init__` you must call the constructor of `Process`.

Comment: I added a line to call: super().__init__. the error remains

Comment: You don't **call** the constructor (same way as any other function).

Comment: Working now by calling Process.__init__(self). Thank you!